# How to make Terraform continue with execution and ignore an error with resource creation during terraform apply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, cni

I am installing CNI using null_resource in terraform. Now if the CNI is already installed the terraform script fails with error:
`exit status 254. Output: │ An error occurred (ResourceInUseException) when calling the CreateAddon │ operation: Addon already exists.`
How can I make terraform continue with execution if the CNI is already installed, rather than failing.

Below is my Configuration for installing CNI:

```
### Installing CNI Addon ###
resource "null_resource" "install-CNI" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = create
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOT
        aws eks create-addon  \
            --cluster-name ${data.aws_eks_cluster.Custom_Dev-cluster-deploy.name} \
            --addon-name vpc-cni \
            --addon-version v1.11.2-eksbuild.1 \
            --service-account-role-arn ${aws_iam_role.Custom_Dev-cluster.arn} \
            --resolve-conflicts OVERWRITE
    EOT
  }
  triggers = {
    "before" = null_resource.eks-config-file.id
  }
}
```

Comment: If you know it's already there why not just remove the offending block?

Answer (score 2):

you can handle the error base on the response. if the command response contains `Addon already exists` you can `exit 0` and return an error if something else, it can be `aws cli` permission or wrong command.

```
resource "null_resource" "install-CNI" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = create
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOT
        RESULT=$(aws eks create-addon --cluster-name ${data.aws_eks_cluster.Custom_Dev-cluster-deploy.name} --addon-name vpc-cni --addon-version v1.11.2-eksbuild.1 --service-account-role-arn ${aws_iam_role.Custom_Dev-cluster.arn} --resolve-conflicts OVERWRITE 2>&1)
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
        echo "Addon installed successfully $RESULT"
        exit 0
        elif [[ "$RESULT" =~ .*"Addon already exists".* ]] 
        then
        echo "Plugin already exists $RESULT" >&2
        exit 0
        else 
        echo "Encounter error $RESULT" >&2
        exit 1
        fi
    EOT
    
  }
  triggers = {
    "before" = null_resource.eks-config-file.id
  }
}
```